# Is it possible to disable default catchall rendering in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to learn how rails handles it's response and rendering, and as such I've been having problems asking the "right" question.

What I'd like to do, keep using a RESTful route setup but have controller methods only respond to formats that I explicitly allow. So in my controller (by method), I'd like a response to only be offered if I had an explicit respond_to block.

I don't want to change my routes (using `format: false` is not the option). I'd like to alter/affect the ActionController default handling so that only the format in a `respond_to` block is handled.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it - this is the default behaviour? If you make a request for js and the controller doesn't respond to it, you'll get a 406 Not Acceptable.

Comment: Not at all... if I make a request for say, users.xyz -- it routes it to the default renderer in ActionController and that gives me an html view.

Comment: "Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client." so the `.xyz` is not really the format of your request.

Comment: Which I thought I understood... here are the accept headers for 3 different requests (xml, html, css), all produced the same: `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`